# PIL or imghdr for image validation

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, imghdr

I'm working on a website that will handle image uploads so I need to verify for valid images,
and I have two options, I either use PIL(Pillow) or the imghdr module.

My question is, which one should I use?
Since PIL is not being mantained will imghdr module do the job?
Which of them is secure and/or efficient?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plese note that PIL and Pillow is not the same package. Pillow is a fork of PIL that is considered to be PIL's successor.

To work with images in a website (I assume because of your tag, that it's a django project), it's recommended to use [Pillow](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/). For example, if you want to use [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#imagefield), it requires the Pillow library.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am currently using Pillow but because I'm not using Django models to save data into SQL(I'm using mongo) I need to validate the ImageField manually before saving the file into system.